# Restructuring the phrase to remove repetition

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-request, sentence-construction, phrases

> Would my knowledge about *the event* make such **events** from occuring ever in future?

Consider the phrase above. **the event** is in reference to a general event which occurs weekly/fortnightly.

Can I use some other structure for the same phrase; so that I won't have to repeat the word `event`? What my actual meaning in context is:

> If I get to know more about the event, will this result in stopping of
>   such events from happening ever in future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I concur with user3169 that a pronoun will solve your problem; but I suggest *one*, since you look to prevent the future occurrence of similar events, not of the same event (which has, after already occurred and therefore cannot be prevented). The reference of *one* may be either forward or backward:

> Would my knowledge of this event prevent similar ones from occurring in the future?
>
> Would my knowledge of this one prevent similar events from occurring in the future?

Even better would be **FumbleFingers**' suggestion:

> Would my knowledge of this event prevent others like it from occurring in the future?

Two other points you do not ask about:

1. *Knowledge* is vague in this context. Your paraphrases suggest that what you mean is something like *deeper understanding* of this event; but your characterization of the event as recurrent suggests it you mean simply that your *familiarity with* or your *awareness of* or  your *having experienced* the event will effect the desired end.
2. *Make ... from occurring* is not idiomatic. *Keep ... from occurring* is OK; but *prevent* is more suitable to formal discourse—and it's shorter, too. And if you will allow me to be really really picky, your *knowledge* cannot itself prevent future occurrences: it can only only *enable **you*** to prevent them.—

Comment: I certainly concur with your reasoning re baldly substituting "it". But it's a stylistic choice *exactly* how you phrase things to avoid repeating the word "event" (which is hardly a mortal sin anyway). I think I might prefer just "others", since the context clearly implies you mean "others *like it*".

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Actually *others like it* would serve even better than *similar ones*, without sacrificing precision. I'm going to incorporate that.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way is to use a pronoun for the second use:

> Would my knowledge about the event *keep* **them** from occuring ever in *the* future?
>
> If I get to know more about the event, will this result in *keeping* **them** from happening ever in *the* future?

In the first phrase, *keep* is a better verb than *make* when referring to a continuing/ongoing activity. In this case, *ever* is probably not needed, other than for emphasis.

If it is not appropriate for some reason, just use a synonym for the second *event* that fits your meaning.

Comment: But OP is looking for his second clause to address similar events (plural), not the one which has already occurred.

Comment: @StoneyB I see your point. I'll edit my answer.